# Adding JavaScript to document with PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Ok, so this should be easy right? 
test.php:

```
function some_javascript() {
        echo "Hello";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Hello')<script>";
}
```

and you'll get an alert window when you try to load your test.php.

I must be missing something because I can't get this to work using a modal window as target and an AJAX request via post.

Here's a basic structure of what I'm trying to do:

index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
 #modal {
    visibility:hidden;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="modal">
    </div>
    <button onclick="call_ajax();">Call Ajax</button>
</body>
</html>
```

call_ajax() sets modal visibility to "visible" and its innerHTML to response text from test.php(I don't write code because I don't seem to have problems here; text is sent just fine (I get "hello") and post data sent is processed as needed). But no alert window! Instead I get "alert('Hello')".

Other than that the code works fine but I can't get javascript to work. 
There must be some detail I'm missing.
Any ideas????

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run `<script>` tags by adding them through `innerHTML`. See this question: [Can scripts be inserted with innerHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml)

Comment: Thanks a lot! That settles it.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Hello')<script>";
```

Should be

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Hello')</script>";
```

Also as someone posted below me, scripts cannot be run in this way.

Comment: Yeah, "/" I missed typing it on here. It's in the original file.

Answer (score 0):

First, script code cannot be inserted as HTML, it will show as such (and it did).

Second, even if you would insert a SCRIPT element in the document, initial parsing is already done and the alert would not be executed.

What you can do is to parse the script code and eval it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #modal {
            visibility:hidden;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function call_ajax() {
            var ajaxData = "Hello\n<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Hello')<\/script>";
            var scriptStartPos = ajaxData.indexOf("<script type='text/javascript'>");
            if(scriptStartPos >= 0) {
                var scriptPos0=scriptStartPos+31;
                var scriptEndPos= ajaxData.indexOf("<\/script>", scriptPos0);
                if(scriptEndPos >= scriptPos0) {
                    eval(ajaxData.substring(scriptPos0,scriptEndPos));
                }
            }
        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="modal">
</div>
<button onclick="call_ajax();">Call Ajax</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Please notice that i used un-escaped single quotes in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Basically `Ajax Request` won't load `Javascript` code.

I am using something like this to get `Javascript` code to work from ajax's `responseText`;

**Javascript :**

```
//pseudo function :
function call_ajax() {
  var ajaxResponse = "some data you have received with ajax"; 

  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = ajaxResponse;
  var script = div.getElementsByTagName("script");
  for(var i=0; i < script.length; i++) {
    try{eval(script[i].innerHTML)}catch(ex){alert(ex)};
  }
};
```

*This code will create a blank `div` element, where it's `innerHTML` will be data loaded with ajax. Javascript will transform your simple text to html nodes, then you can find if response contains `Javascript` code, by finding "script" tags, then just try to eval the `javascript` code to execute the code, now you're done.*

P.S: In my vision it is not a good idea to load javascript with ajax. Look what if you do two ajax requests to the same javascript code : it will load the same code twice, so the code may become buggy because of this.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of Javascript libraries to do this for you.

Try lazyload:
https://github.com/rgrove/lazyload